# Using an if condition inside a V-For Loop in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having a problem passing an if condition inside a `v-for` loop in VueJS. I want to see if a value in the text field is greater than 30 to give an alert but I can't figure out how i can call my function inside the loop. Here is my code: I have tried using `v-if` but still not lucky

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"> 
 </script>
 <tbody>
<tr> v-for="item in marksData">
<td>{{item.studentName}}</td>
<td>{{item.studentRegNo}}</td>
<td><input v-model.number="item.cat1Marks" required="required" /> *...V-if 
to check the condition here.... or call any function to check*</td>
<td><button v-on:click.prevent="saveMarks(item)" 
type="submit">Save</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
var subjectStudentsVM = new Vue({
      el: "#subjectStudentsSection",
      data: function() {
        return {
          id: '',
          studentRegNo: '',
          studentName: '',
          marksData: Array(),
        }
      },

      created: function() {
        this.getAllSubjects();
      },
      methods: {
        getAllSubjectStudents: function(subject) {
          var self = this;
          console.log(this.subject.subjectCode)
          axios.get("/Marks/students/" + 
      this.subject.subjectCode).then(function(response) {

            this.marksData = response.data;

          }.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error while fetching student data: ' + error)
          })
        },
        computed:{
          CheckData(item) {
          if (item.cat1Marks > 30 && item.cat1Marks > 0) {
            alert("Marks should be less than 30");
          }
          console.log(mark);
          return mark;
        }
        }
```

Comment: First thing first: `<tr> v-for="item in marksData">` should be `<tr v-for="item in marksData">`

Comment: I want to use V-if to check item.cat1Marks

Comment: if you want to check the input then I think it shouldn't be a function but a computed prop.

Comment: Maybe, rather than adding a comment, you should update your question embedding where you need `v-if`. Plus, clearing the typo I have mentioned.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chvd4e3k/1/
Check out this fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question. I think you should check the `input` first. Then return the `alert()` if it's necessary.

inside methods

```
giveAlert(){
    alert("Marks should be less than 30");
}
```

inside computed:

```
checkInput(val){
     if (val > 30 && val > 0) {
          this.giveAlert()
     } else {//do nothing}
}
```

Also mentioned in the comments. You should correct the typo of `v-for`.

Answer (score 0):

the html will not cause a alert it's self so you have to run the checkdata in the created function.

```
created:function(){
this.getAllSubjects();
for(var i=0;i<this.marksData.length;i++){
    var item=this.marksData[i];
    if(item.cat1marks>30){
        alert("marks should be less than 30");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Computed variable are defined as functions cause they react on changes in the reactive varables of the vue component. But they are not designed to expect any variable passing them directly.

Use subcomponent created hook like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <p v-for="student in marksData">
      <mystudent :student="student" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <script>
  var app = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: function() {
        return {
          marksData: [{
            studentName: 'Alan',
            studentRegNo: 1,
            cat1Marks: 21
          },{
            studentName: 'Jessica',
            studentRegNo:2,
            cat1Marks: 31
          },{
            studentName: 'Joe',
            studentRegNo: 3,
            cat1Marks: 4
          }],
        }
      },
      components: {
        Mystudent: {
          props: ['student'],
          created() {
            if (this.student.cat1Marks > 30) alert(`Student ${ this.student.studentName } reached ${ this.student.cat1Marks } mark`)
          },
          render (h) {
          return h('span', `Name: ${ this.student.studentName } RegNo: ${ this.student.studentRegNo } Marcs: ${ this.student.cat1Marks }`)
          }
        }
      }
  });
</script>
```

UPDATED

After the comment i realized that i didn't understood the question
So here is updated code example, where the score check is in method section not in computed and the trigger is the @change event. Notice the @change triggers first when the focus is taken out of the input field.

```
<div id="app">
    <p v-for="(student, i) in marksData">
      Student: {{ student.studentName }} Mark: <input v-model="student.cat1Marks" type="text" @change="checkStudent(student)">
    </p>
  </div>
  <script>
  var app = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: function() {
        return {
          test: 1,
          marksData: [{
            studentName: 'Alan',
            studentRegNo: 1,
            cat1Marks: 21
          },{
            studentName: 'Jessica',
            studentRegNo:2,
            cat1Marks: 31
          },{
            studentName: 'Joe',
            studentRegNo: 3,
            cat1Marks: 4
          }],
        }
      },
      methods: {
        checkStudent (student) {
          if (student.cat1Marks > 30) alert(`Student ${student.studentName } reached ${ student.cat1Marks } mark`)
        }
      }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but what I want if a user enters the value like 32 in the text field and alert pops up to show that value should not exceed 30.

Comment: Then use @change="CheckData(item)" event and move the checking logic (CheckData) from computed to methods section.

Comment: can we make as mandatory to change the value to be less than 30 instead of alert message @MarekTuczykont

Answer (score 0):

```
   For anyone having a similar problem I added this function


     up(item){
          if (item.cat1Marks > 30) {
              item.cat1Marks=0;
                  alert("Marks cannot be greater than 30")
          }else{}
          },
  //and called this function in my input
      <td> <input  type="text" name="cat1Marks" 
      v-model.number="item.cat1Marks" v on:input="up(item)" 
       required="required" /></td>
```